# How to change an Adress in a loop

Tags: c, for-loop, eeprom

I want to change an Address in a for loop :

```
for (int i = 0, a = kali.CalibNo; i <= (kali.CalibNo-1) && mess.j > 0; i++, a--) {
  mess.stc[i] = ((-mess.Acal[a][0]) + (mess.Acal[a - 1][0]))
          / (-val.Value[a] + val.Value[a - 1]);                  
  mess.tcal[i] = (mess.Acal[a][1] + 273.1 + mess.Acal[a - 1][1] + 273.1)
          / 2;
  mess.Stcal[i] = (double) -mess.stc[i] / mess.tcal[i];
  mess.Stcal[i] = EEPROM_WRITE(EEPROM_ADRESS_cal(i), &mess.Stcal[i], 4);
}
```

Stcal[i] is an array of 5 doubles and **EEPROM_ADRESS_cal** is my address, but i cannot define an address like this with (i)... Sadly i can only define them one by one:

```
#define EEPROM_ADDRESS_cal0  0x1E
#define EEPROM_ADDRESS_cal1  0x22
#define EEPROM_ADDRESS_cal2  0x26
```

does somebody have any Idea how i could change the index of the Address, so it will count up in the for loop?

Comment: Aside: generally speaking, `i <= (kali.CalibNo-1)` may very well lead to a runtime error. Please use `i < kali.CalibNo`

Comment: Can you `#define EEPROM_ADDRESS_cal(i) (0x1E + ((i) * 4))`? This way, you can use it like `EEPROM_ADDRESS_cal(0)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the macros. Keep it simple.

```
const uint8_t eeprom_address [n] = 
{
  0x1E,
  ... 
};

EEPROM_WRITE(eeprom_address[i], &mess.Stcal[i], 4);
```

Although in a real embedded systems application with on-chip eeprom, the `double` array would already be memory mapped, so then you won't need this table, but just the address of each item. In case this is for an external, serial eeprom, then that's another story.

Comment: I receive multiple definitions somehow, You know what could cause this?

Comment: c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.7.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.9-2020-q2-update.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: ./Messung/Messung.o:C:/Projekt/Messgeraet/TouchGFXProject/Debug/../Settings/Settings.h:45: multiple definition of `EEPROM_ADRESS_AD'; ./Core/Src/main.o:C:/Projekt/Messgeraet/TouchGFXProject/Debug/../Settings/Settings.h:45: first defined here

Comment: @MarcHammer That means: don't use the same name for different things. Often you get that linker error when you have crappilly written headers without include guards and/or with variable or function definitions inside them.